# Connecting cellphone to android studio for developing

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to get my phone connected so I can use it to test things I am trying to develop. My phone is LG G3. I verified that it is in developer mode. When I connect it to my computer I see the phone in the device manager.When I right click on it and choose update driver, and search online for update I get a message that I already have the latest version installed. When I open Android Studio and connect my phone it doesn't show up in available devices. Does anybody have an idea what I am missing?

Comment: Install `LG Bridge` to get all drivers (adb, MTP....), enable USB debugging on phone and... enjoy!

Comment: Yes. I verified that the phone is in debug mode. When I connect it I see a little bug icon in the notification area, and when I went to the settings and tapped on the Build number it said no need, you are already a developer.

Comment: Where can I download LG Bridge?

Comment: OK, very seriously. I went to LG.com, found the support section and clicked on software,firmware and drivers. It takes me to a page where among other things I can download LG Bridge. When I click on the link I get a popup that says this page is not available. Does anybody know of an alternative for downloading LG Bridge?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and advice I finally managed to find the driver that I needed.
In the interests of helping anyone else who runs into this problem, here is what I found:

1. Go to the LG UK site:  http://www.lg.com/uk/support/software-firmware
2. Select your model number
3. On the page that opens there are a few options for updating. I chose option 2 (USB Driver), and downloaded the installer.